# How can I build a query that returns all attachments of a page and it's children pages?

Tags: wp-query, attachments, children

I'm using this query to return attachments of a page.

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
```

Is there a way to adapt this in order to return attachments for the current page *and* the attachments of all child pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posts query is not recursive by nature. And I don't think that `post_parent` accepts multiple IDs, so you will likely need to loop and run this for multiple pages or play with query filters to do this in less requests (if performance becomes an issue).